# Why are there elements of order $6$ in the permutation group $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I understand that an element in $S_5$ can have an order $6$ if it is product of two disjoint cycles of one of length $2$ and another of length $3$, but I do not understand why these elements have an order of $6$ since there are not any cycles in $S_5$ of length $6$. Please explain how this is possible.

Comment: Why in order to have an element of order $6$ we need a cycle of length $6$?

Comment: Order $6$ doesn't mean there is a cycle of size $6.$

Comment: One way to look at it is, if you consider the permutation acting on pairs of elements, some of the cycles have size $6.$ For example, the permutation $(123)(45)$ when acting on pairs sends $$(1,4)\to (2,5)\to(3,4)\to(1,5)\to(2,4)\to(3,5)\to(1,4),$$ which is a cycle of length six.

Comment: In general, the order of a permutation is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles

Comment: That's not always true. @MatteoAldovardi For example, in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z,$ $1$ is order $6,$ $2$ is order three, and $1+2=3$ is order $2.$ Your statement is true if $r,q$ are relatively prime, I believe, but not generally true.

Comment: For another example, in $\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z$, $2$ is order $15,$ $3$ is order $10,$ and $2+3$ is order $6.$ @MatteoAldovardi

Comment: Imagine that you have a combination of two gears with a gear ratio $2:3$. So if the smaller gear rotates a full revolution in 2 seconds, the bigger one will need 3 seconds. Given a starting position how many seconds will it take that both gears have simultaneously returned to their original orientations?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

It is sufficient to provide one example.  Consider

$$\sigma=(123)(45).$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
\sigma^2&=(132),\\
\sigma^3&=(45),\\
\sigma^4&=(123),\\
\sigma^5&=(132)(45),\\
\sigma^6&={\rm id}_{S_5}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the following theorem.

> **Theorem** *(Order of a Permutation)* : The order of a permutation of a finite set written in **disjoint cycle**
> form is the **least common multiple** of the **lengths** of the cycles.

Comment: And also think why this needs to be true! Start with simple examples, i.e., take your own question as an example and find its order. Generalize this and you've got the proof.